# I can't serve gunicorn requests from nginx

Tags: nginx, gunicorn

I have a react web app that is run on an nginx server. The server runs on port 80.

Its conf is like this:

```
location / { 
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
    proxy_read_timeout 300s;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

Gunicorn is binded to my flask app and runs on 127.0.0.1:5000. When I do this I can't see my website. It says

```
This site can’t be reached 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
```

Ideally Nginx would serve the static files over port 80 and when a fetch request is made on the react side, it would be passed along to gunicorn and flask on 127.0.0.1:5000

When I set the location to location /insert_email (my react fetch) I can load the website but I never receive the email insert request on my Gunicorn server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample NGINX config which I know to work as a reverse proxy with Gunicorn.

```
#Config Contents
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  site.your.domain;
    # Or use the following if you do not have a domain
    #server_name 123.123.123.123;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    }
}
```

The Gunicorn Run string looks like

```
gunicorn --bind localhost:5000 flask_app:app
```

As a sanity check, you can check which processes are listening to which ports using

```sh
lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
```

Make sure your server allows traffic on port 80 from at least your IP address.